# Choosing between MPMoviePlayerViewController and AV Foundation classes to play HTTP Video

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

My app requires some video to be streamed from AWS/CloudFront URL. I guess both MoviePlayerViewController and AV Foundation classes can use HTTL Streaming URL but what exactly the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize player UI, you should use AV foundation.